# Ubuntu mount image file from VM virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, virtualbox, qnx

I have Ubuntu 17.10 on USB Flash drive and in VM VirtualBox.

I have a QNX4 image file on an external hard drive that I can mount on the computer running from the Ubuntu 17.10 USB flash drive.

I have another computer with Ubuntu 17.10 running in VM VirtualBox Version 5.2.2 r119230 (Qt5.6.2) that gives me an error when trying to mount the QNX4.img file.  The error I get is

```
"/mnt/QNX4_Drive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."
```

I have the external hard drive shared from host to virtual machine.

I perform on system running Ubuntu from USB

```
modprobe qnx4
mount -t qnx4 QNX4.img /mnt/QNX4_Drive -o loop
```

which works fine and I can access the files.

on Windows 7 pro system running VM VirtualBox running Ubuntu

```
    modprobe qnx4
    mount -t qnx4 /media/sf_C_DRIVE/QNX4.img /mnt/QNX4_Drive -o loop
```

Produces the error message listed above

Is there something else I need to do on the VM VirtualBox to be able to mount image files on the host machine?

Comment: have you simply tried attaching the ISO/IMG as a virtual CD/DVD ?

Comment: Tried to connect using Devices -> Optical Drives -> Choose disk image...

VirtualBox - Error
Failed to open the disk imiage file

Thus this does not work.